# Mod Rewrite Page Not Found

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

This should be easy but I can't get it to work.

I want this url:

```
local.thissite.com/dashboard/blog/123/12
```

To go to:

```
local.thissite.com/dashboard/post.php?id=12&bid=123
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dashboard/blog/([a-z0-9]{3,24})/([0-9]{1,6})$ /dashboard/blog-post.php?id=$2&bid=$1 [NC]
```

I just get a 404 Not Found error

```
The requested URL /dashboard/blog/123/12 was not found on this server.
```

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^dashboard/blog/([a-z0-9]{3,24})/([0-9]{1,6})$` and make sure that a space and `/dashboard/post.php?id=$2&bid=$1 [NC]` immediately follows it instead of being on a new line

Comment: There is a space it just wrapped in Stack Overflow

Comment: That's incorrect. Stack Overflow does not wrap code sections.

Comment: Ok, I added the new line so it was visible without scrolling.   It's fixed now.

Comment: Okay, so did you try my suggestion? What was the result? It works at https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: A space between the two arguments?  Yes, same result

Comment: You may have overlooked an important detail in my first comment. I suggest re-reading it.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see it

Comment: Remove the slash `/` before dashboard

Comment: I did that too.  I think there's something wrong with my Apache

Comment: It works for me on the madewithlove tester as well

Comment: I assume that the tester site is using the latest Apache htaccess logic so if your server is Apache 2.2 then you could have some incompatibilities. You should try this rewrite rule without any other rules in the htaccess file and also remove any parent folder htaccess files. If you are the server administrator then make sure there are no httpd.conf rewrite rules which are messing with you. As always, make sure to check your logs for any errors. If you get really really stuck then you can try `LogLevel info rewrite:trace5` to get the details of the rewrites.

Comment: @anubhava RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^dashboard/blog/([a-z0-9]{3,24})/([0-9]{1,6})$ /dashboard/blog-post.php?id=$2&bid=$1 [NC]

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I have Apache version 2.4.18

Comment: I saw that online tested and did get a 500 error

Comment: Is there any other .htaccess in system?

Comment: @anubhava No, not in that path

Comment: Try this rule in `/dashboard/.htaccess`: `RewriteRule ^blog/([a-z0-9]{3,24})/(\d{1,6})/?$ blog-post.php?id=$2&bid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: @anubhava no that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the restriction for the first parameter requires a length of at least 3.  My test url only had 2 digits.